# Stop recursion of find command if match found

Tags: bash, gnu-findutils

Using GNU findutils, I need to search a directory tree for a certain file. If the file has been found for a given branch, I want to prevent find from recursing further into the branch. Say I want to find the file foo, and this is my directory tree:

```
├── a
│   ├── a1
│   │   └── foo
│   └── foo
├── b
└── c
    └── foo
```

Given I am searching the tree above, I want to find a/foo and c/foo. However, I don't want to find a/a1/foo since I already found foo in a parent directory to a1.
It seems I should use the -prune flag to the find command and I found this link https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24557/how-do-i-stop-a-find-from-descending-into-found-directories, for example, but I cannot make it work. My attempts include:

```
$ find -name foo -type f -prune
./a/a1/foo <- Unwanted hit
./a/foo
./c/foo
```

and

```
$ find -name foo -type f -prune -exec find ../foo -type f {} \;
find: paths must precede expression: ./a/a1/foo
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
find: paths must precede expression: ./a/foo
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
find: paths must precede expression: ./c/foo
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

Comment: Why isn't `./a/foo` the unwanted hit? Are we interested in that hit that is less deeper? What if `mkdir -p a/a1 a/b1; touch a/a1/foo a/b1/foo`. Then is `a/a1/foo` or `a/b1/foo` the unwanted hit? Or it doesn't matter, at least one should do it, no matter where?

Comment: @KamilCuk as I understood, in the example you give, both `a/a1/foo` and `a/b1/foo` should be returned.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will print the directories that contain `foo`, and will not recurse in their subdirectories:

```
find -type d -exec test -f {}/foo \; -print -prune
```

The behavior for `{}/foo` [is explicitly left undefined by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html):

> If a utility_name or argument string contains the two characters "{}", but not just the two characters "{}", it is implementation-defined whether find replaces those two characters or uses the string without change.

but works as expected with GNU `find` (and you tagged the question with [gnu-findutils](/questions/tagged/gnu-findutils)). As Kamil Cuk rightly suggests in the comments, if you're using non-GNU `find` or if you want a more portable solution, use:

```
find -type d -exec sh -c 'test -f "$1"/foo' -- {} \; -print -prune
```

Comment: And i think we can even get away from posixly undefined by just invoking the shell and passing path by parameter `-exec sh -c 'test -f "$1"/foo' -- {} \;`.

Comment: @chepner: that wouldn't work: the `-prune` predicate must be applied to a directory. Regarding the output, it's quite easy to modify the statement to append `/foo` to it.

Comment: Oops, for some reason in my tests I was making directories instead of regular files as the candidate matches, so `-prune` was coincidentally working for me.

Answer (score 2):

it can't be done easily with find `-prune` because it works on directories and find's basic conditions are over current file.

an alternative could be to do it with bash programmatically, using recursive function, basically

```
rec_run() {
    local file
    for file in "${1:-.}"/*; do
        # to filter 'file=*' when no match is found
        if [[ ! -e $file ]]; then
            continue
        fi

        # do something with file
        echo "$file"

        # to filter known hard links
        if [[ $file = */. ]] || [[ $file = */.. ]]; then
            continue
        fi

        # if is a directory recursive call
        if [[ -d $file ]]; then
            rec_run "$file";
        fi
    done
}
```

and changing the part `# do something` with

```
    if [[ -f $file/foo ]]; then
        echo "$file/foo"
        continue
    fi
```

here `foo` is hardcoded but could be passed as second function argument

Note `${1:-.}` is to take the first argument as root directory or `.` if not passed

Comment: yes i left it in case OP wanted to match "hidden files" `.*` and in this case pattern would be `.*`

Comment: Ok, makes sense!